# Pandas pivot a multi-line header CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a `csv` file that looks like:

```
   Group A             Group B             Group C                 
ID Date1     Date2     Date1     Date2     Date1     Date2
0  0.030626  0.494912  0.364742  0.320088  0.364742  0.364742
1  0.178368  0.857469  0.628677  0.705226  0.364742  0.364742
```

How do I read it into a dataframe and pivot such that the following table will result?

```
ID Date   Group A   Group B   Group C
0  Date1  0.030626  0.364742  0.364742
0  Date2  0.494912  0.320088  0.364742
1  Date1  0.178368  0.628677  0.364742
1  Date2  0.857469  0.705226  0.364742
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform your dataframe, you can `stack()` it and then `reset_index()`:

**Code:**

```
df = df.stack().reset_index().rename(
    columns={'level_0': 'ID', 'level_1': 'Date'})
print(df)
```

**Test Data:**

```
csv_data = StringIO('\n'.join(x.strip() for x in u"""
    Group A,Group A,Group B,Group B,Group C,Group C
    Date1,Date2,Date1,Date2,Date1,Date2
    0.030626,0.494912,0.364742,0.320088,0.364742,0.364742
    0.178368,0.857469,0.628677,0.705226,0.364742,0.364742
""".split('\n')[1:-1]))

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_data, sep=',', header=[0, 1])
```

**Results:**

```
   ID   Date   Group A   Group B   Group C
0   0  Date1  0.030626  0.364742  0.364742
1   0  Date2  0.494912  0.320088  0.364742
2   1  Date1  0.178368  0.628677  0.364742
3   1  Date2  0.857469  0.705226  0.364742
```

**Test Data 2:**

And if your data is not CSV and is actually formatted as in your question:

```
data = StringIO(
u"""           Group A             Group B             Group C                 
    ID Date1     Date2     Date1     Date2     Date1     Date2
    0  0.030626  0.494912  0.364742  0.320088  0.364742  0.364742
    1  0.178368  0.857469  0.628677  0.705226  0.364742  0.364742
""")

df = pd.read_fwf(data, colspecs='infer', header=[0, 1]).rename(
    columns={'Unnamed: 0_level_0': 'ID',
             'Unnamed: 2_level_0': 'Group A',
             'Unnamed: 4_level_0': 'Group B',
             'Unnamed: 6_level_0': 'Group C'})
del df['ID']
```